# Illustrator glow effect not shown in pdf after saving

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, cs6, latex

I am relatively new to Illustrator. I use version CS6 and I just discovered that when I apply an outer glow effect it is not visible in the PDF after saving apart from when you make the effect really strong. I am currently writing my thesis using latex and when I include the PDF in my latex document no outer glow effect is visible at all. Has anyone discovered a similar behaviour?

Comment: Does it appear in the PDF if viewed in Reader or Acrobat?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 4):

It was really just the PDF viewer I used. In my case, it was **Preview** from Apple.

Using `Adobe Reader`, the glowing effect was visible.

Comment: This is why I asked the question in the comments. Apple's Preview application is a **horrible** PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out it just doesn't show in Preview.  Try opening the pdf back up in Illustrator to check it's really there.